# multiple for loop to select special rows from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

I have a large data frame in python and I want to select specific rows based on multiple for loops. Some columns contain lists in them. My final goal is to generate some optimization constraints and pass them through another software:

```
   T        S        W     Arrived    Departed     
  [1,2]    [4,2]     1        8          10
  [3,4,5]   [3]      1        12         18
  [6,7]    [1,2]     2        10         11
    .        .       .        .          .
    .        .       .        .          .

  def Cons(row):

    if row['W'] == w and sum(pd.Series(row['T']).isin([t])) != 0 and sum(pd.Series(row['S']).isin([s])) != 0:
           return 1

  for w in range(50):
      for s in range(30):
          for t in range(12):
              df.Situation = df.apply(Cons, axis = 1)
              A = df[ (df.Situation == 1) ] 
              A1 = pd.Series(A.Arrived).tolist()
              D1 = pd.Series(A.Departed).tolist()
              Time = tuplelist(zip(A1,D1))
```

How can I efficiently do this because going through multiple for loops takes a long time to run?

Comment: Judging from your code, the nested loops just go through 50 * 30 * 12 = 18000 iterations. It shouldn't be an issue assuming the the body of the most inner loop doesn't do anything computationally intensive.

Comment: @xuanluong, his algorithm is `O(n^3)` which is not that good for big data - but for small iterations I agree with you is not that bad

Comment: @coder hmm, big data, but how big?

Maybe the OP should give more context on the order of magnitude of the data. Otherwise whether cubic time complexity is good enough or too slow is just anyone's guess.

Comment: Running with this format is very slow.

Comment: I edited my primary question. Sorry, I'm a beginner and it may look not very efficient in every step.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are constantly adjusting your dataframe with each nested loop where `A` is re-written over each time and does not yield a growing result but only of the very, very last iteration.

But consider creating a cross join of all ranges and then checking the equality logic:

```
wdf = pd.DataFrame({'w': range(50), 'key': 1})
sdf = pd.DataFrame({'s': range(30), 'key': 1})
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'t': range(12), 'key': 1})

dfs = [wdf, sdf, tdf]

# DATA FRAME OF CROSS PRODUCT w X s X T (N = 18,000)
rangedf = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['key']), dfs)[['w','s','t']]
#    w  s  t
# 0  0  0  0
# 1  0  0  1
# 2  0  0  2
# 3  0  0  3
# 4  0  0  4
# ...

def Cons(row):    
    if any((rangedf['w'].isin([row['W']])) & (rangedf['t'].isin([row['T']])) & \
           (rangedf['s'].isin([row['S']]))) == True:
        return 1

df.Situation = df.apply(Cons, axis = 1)
A = df[ (df.Situation == 1) ].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Does your code allow me to use 'A' in every iteration because I want to use that?

Comment: Iterations have been removed here. My understanding was you want only one *A* dataframe not 18,000 ones! Please show how you want to use each *A*.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to run through all those combinations of w, t, s? And what do you end up doing with the 18,000 *Time* objects? And what module is `tuplelist()`?

Comment: I need to add one constraint per combination to an optimization problem. I use 'Time' object to find the value of 'Arrived' and 'Departed' for selected rows.